# A likely obvious question concerning sufficient conditions for (sub)group equality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the following true?

Let $G$ be a finite group, with subgroups $H$ and $K$. Then, $H \le K$ and $|H| = |K|$ if and only if  $H = K$.

It seems like it most certainly should be true, but I'm actually having trouble proving the "$ \implies$" direction.

Comment: If you have a finite set $S$ with a subset $P\subset S$, and $|P|=|S|$, then $P=S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G$ is finite, we know $H$ and $K$ must be finite. If $H$ is a subgroup of $K$, then it is, in particular, a subset of $K$. So, if in addition $|H|=|K|$, it must follow that $H=K$.